# node-redis promisification using bluebird

Tags: node.js, promise, node-redis

I'm trying to use promises with node-redis package, but I can't use on.connect() method.

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient();

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

// callback version
app.get('/redis', function(req, res) {
  client.set("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value", function(err, reply) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(reply);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});

// promisified version
app.get('/redis', function(req, res) {
  return client.setAsync("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value").then(function(return) {
    console.log(return); // returns OK
    client.quit();
  });
});
```

But I am stuck with the one below, how can I promisify it?

```
// example
client.on("connect", function () {
    client.set("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value", redis.print);
    client.get("foo_rand000000000000", redis.print);
});
```

I tried the one below but it doesn't work, I can't see the response on the command line:

```
app.get('/redis', function(req, res) {
  return client.onAsync("connect").then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like Freyday siad, `on` is not async method, but an event emitter, so I would strongly discourage you from promisfying it, but hey, if you are insistant you could do something like:

```
let _connectResolve, _connectReject, onConnected = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _connectResolve = resolve;
    _connectReject = reject;
 }), redis = require("redis"),
 client = redis.createClient();

client.on('connect', _connectResolve);

// usage example:
onConnected.then(() => {
  client.setAsync("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value").then(redis.print);
    client.getAsync("foo_rand000000000000").then(redis.print);
});
```

if your worry is, you have to wait for client to connect before you get/ set stuff, you can chain all your calls to onConnected promise. e.g:

```
app.get('/redis', (req, res) => {
  onConnected
    .then(() => client.setAsync("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value"))
    .then(() => res.end());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `client.on()` method is coming from the `EventEmitter` prototype which the redis client likely inherits from. You could try to walk the prototype chain and promisify it as well, but I'd probably just handle it myself like this:

```
function onConnect(client) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.on('connect', function(err) {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      return resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

Then you'll be able to use it like this:

```
app.get('/redis', function(req, res) {
  return onConnect(client)
    .then(function() {
      return client.setAsync("foo_rand000000000000", "some fantastic value")
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result); // returns OK
      client.quit();
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```